# combine INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE queries into one

Tags: mysql

I have a main table that  I use in my application called t_media. The dataset is from an external source that is updated every day. I download the dataset to a temporary table called t_media_temp every day. I need to do three things:

- Insert a record from t_media_temp into t_media if it doesn't already exist
- Update a record in t_media if the date is different in t_media_temp
- Delete a record from t_media if it does not exist in t_media_temp

In the current situation I use the 3 queries beneath, but is there an easy way to combine it into a single query?

```
/* Insert */
INSERT INTO t_media (`col_1`, `col_2`, `col_3`, `col_x`) 
SELECT (`col_1`, `col_2`, `col_3`, `col_x`) 
FROM t_media_temp AS t1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT * FROM t_media AS t2 
    WHERE t1.col_1 = t2.col_1 
)

/* Update */
UPDATE t_media, t_media_temp SET 
    t_media.col_1 = t_media_temp.col_1, 
    t_media.col_2 = t_media_temp.col_2, 
    t_media.col_3 = t_media_temp.col_3, 
    t_media.col_x = t_media_temp.col_x 
WHERE
    t_media.col_1 = t_media_temp.col_1 
AND 
    t_media.col_2 != t_media_temp.col_2

/* Delete */
DELETE FROM t_media WHERE col_1 NOT IN ( SELECT col_1 FROM t_media_temp )
```

col_1 is always a unique value in the table.

Comment: why logic around `t_media.col_2 != t_media_temp.col_2` absent in insert query?

Answer (score 2):

According to documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

You can mix your INSERT and UPDATE like this:

```
INSERT INTO t_media (`col_1`, `col_2`, `col_3`, `col_x`) 
SELECT (`col_1`, `col_2`, `col_3`, `col_x`) 
FROM t_media_temp AS t1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    t_media.col_2 = t1.col_2, 
    t_media.col_3 = t2.col_3, 
    t_media.col_x = t3.col_x
```

But there is no way to mix INSERT or UPDATE with DELETE

Comment: Is col_1  automatically recognised as the duplicate key? And there is another condition... It has to be updated only is col_2 doesn't match.

Comment: @web_student yes, col_1 will be automatically recognised as dupe if its a unique key (or part of it). abut col_2 i ve asked before. why we not see workaround it in your INSERT query? is it any key in table structure? can you post original fields names, not col_X?

Comment: what do you mean workaround in INSERT query? There is only one unique identifier and that is col_1. All the other values may not be unique. The table consists of 50+ columns.